# How to play a embedded code in lightbox type popup

Tags: php

How to play a embedded code in lightbox type pop up?

Here is the whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
    <title>FancyBox 1.3.1 | Demonstration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
            *   Examples - images
            */

            $("a#example1").fancybox({
                'titleShow'     : false
            });

            $("a#example2").fancybox({
                'titleShow'     : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
            });

            $("a#example3").fancybox({
                'titleShow'     : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none'
            });

            $("a#example4").fancybox();

            $("a#example5").fancybox({
                'titlePosition' : 'inside'
            });

            $("a#example6").fancybox({
                'titlePosition' : 'over'
            });

            $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            });

            /*
            *   Examples - various
            */

            $("#various1").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });

            $("#various2").fancybox();

            $("#various3").fancybox({
                'width'             : '75%',
                'height'            : '75%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });

            $("#various4").fancybox({
                'padding'           : 0,
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <p>
        <a id="example1" href="./example/1_b.jpg"><img alt="example1" src="./example/1_s.jpg" /></a>

        <a id="example2" href="./example/2_b.jpg"><img alt="example2" src="./example/2_s.jpg" /></a>

        <a id="example3" href="./example/3_b.jpg"><img alt="example3" src="./example/3_s.jpg" /></a>
    </p>
</div>
<div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This above code working for image perfectly. But how shall i play the embedded code instead of image.

Here is the sample embedded code.

```
<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/WUW5g-sL8pU&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/WUW5g-sL8pU&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several lightbox scripts that allow you to automatically embed a youtube clip in an overlay.

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/ is one, jQuery in this case but there are dozens more if you google for it, jquery, prototype, mootools, ...

Comment: Hi Ramakers... One small prob with that script... Its only working if we give the URL but if we give the embedded code it's not working.. Is there any other suggestion

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to extract the video id from the embedcode and form an url with that. As far as i know a lightbox script that works with the embedcodes is something i haven't seen before so i don't think its possible as far as i know.